ros2_control publishes higher velocities to odom than the real robot goes at
I've followed Josh Newans' tutorial for a ROS2 robot and have a similar setup to his. However, when I run my robot with the diff_drive_controller from ros2_control and online_async from slam_toolbox and try to drive it around, the odom published by ros2_control says the robot is moving, and especially turning, much faster than it really is! Sometimes the system corrects the robot's position using the map, but it still causes big discrepancies sometimes.
I've tried increasing the wheel_separation_multiplier and decreasing the right_ and left_wheel_radius_multiplier, even to extreme values, but all those do is try to send faster commands to my wheels (which doesn't work) and the robot still moves more slowly in real life than in the simulation. Adding covariance values just eases the discrepancies a bit but doesn't really solve the problem.
In short, I need to find a way to make ros2_control keep in mind the robot moves a bit slower than commanded.
This is my controller yaml file:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 30
    #use_sim_time: true

    diff_cont:
      type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController

    joint_broad:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

diff_cont:
  ros__parameters:

    publish_rate: 50.0

    base_frame_id: base_link

    left_wheel_names: ["FL_wheel_joint" , "RL_wheel_joint"]
    right_wheel_names: ["FR_wheel_joint", "RR_wheel_joint"]
    wheel_separation: 0.4
    wheel_radius: 0.05

    use_stamped_vel: false

    # open_loop: false    

    wheels_per_side: 2
    # wheel_separation_multiplier: 10.0
    # left_wheel_radius_multiplier: 0.1
    # right_wheel_radius_multiplier: 0.1

    # odom_frame_id: odom
    # pose_covariance_diagonal: x
    # twist_covariance_diagonal: x
    open_loop: true
    enable_odom_tf: true

    # cmd_vel_timeout: x
    # publish_limited_velocity: x
    velocity_rolling_window_size: 10

Also, here's my ros2_control xacro file, in case it's of any use:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    
    <xacro:unless value="$(arg sim_mode)">
        <ros2_control name="RobotSystem" type="system">
            <hardware>
                <plugin>diffdrive_arduino/DiffDriveArduino</plugin>
                <param name="FL_wheel_name">FL_wheel_joint</param>
                <param name="FR_wheel_name">FR_wheel_joint</param>
                <param name="RL_wheel_name">RL_wheel_joint</param>
                <param name="RR_wheel_name">RR_wheel_joint</param>
                <param name="loop_rate">30</param>
                <param name="device">/dev/ttyACM0</param>
                <param name="baud_rate">57600</param>
                <param name="timeout">1000</param>
                <param name="enc_counts_per_rev">3436</param>
            </hardware>
            <joint name="FL_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="FR_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="RL_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="RR_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
        </ros2_control>
    </xacro:unless>

    <xacro:if value="$(arg sim_mode)">
        <ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
            <hardware>
                <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
            </hardware>
            <joint name="FL_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="FR_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="RL_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="RR_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
        </ros2_control>
    </xacro:if>
    
    <gazebo>
        <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
            <parameters>$(find robot)/config/my_controllers.yaml</parameters>
        <parameters>$(find robot)/config/gaz_ros2_ctl_use_sim.yaml</parameters>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

</robot>


Please add the controller config file, otherwise it's impossible to guess where the error could be.

@ChristophFroehlich OK you have it now

do you have feedback (position/velocity) from your wheels?

@ChristophFroehlich No, I'm running in open loop mode as I don't have encoders.

may this be the problem, that the wheels rotate at a wrong speed?

@ChristophFroehlich Well, be it due to mechanical limitations or some other reason, they are rotating slower than the ros2_control odom predicts. What I don't know is how to make both of them agree.

the wheel speed is the input of the odom. if wheels speeds are wrong it is not the fault of the odom

@ChristophFroehlich I presume you mean the calculated speed? What I need to do is apply a reduction factor to account for whatever is making my real wheels slower, but I don't know how to without modifying the actual commands to the wheels as well.

the controller sends a desired speed to the hardware, and in open loop method you don't have any measurements for odometry, it just uses the commands to calculate odometry. If the motors don't reach this velocity, then odometry obviously is off. If this is the case, you really should calibrate your motors.

@ChristophFroehlich Calibrate them? I have a simple setup with 4 12V motors connected to a L298N motor driver. They're not the most efficient, so maybe some of the energy is going there, but that leaves me with no option but to modify something in the software side.

Do you use PWM for the motor driver?
I suggest that you measure the speed of the wheels and calibrate the gain from desired velocity to PWM output.
btw: how can you have state interfaces of position/velocity if you don't have a sensor?

@ChristophFroehlich Yes, I'm using https://github.com/joshnewans/diffdrive_arduino with https://github.com/joshnewans/ros_arduino_bridge. I'm not very knowledgeable about ROS, but I guess the command and state interfaces are being calculated only from the commands sent due to it being in open loop mode. I'm not really sure how I'd modify the packages, though, as the PWM values seem to depend on the velocities commanded in the first place by ros2_control...

no, the code you are referencing uses encoder for the state interfaces. enc_counts_per_rev is the "gain" of the analog output, how did you choose that? diff_drive_controller command interfaces is rad/s, you have to ensure that the wheel speed is correct. Changing the geometric parameters does not help because it is used for IK and FK (odometry) in the same manner in open loop mode.

@ChristophFroehlich The 3436 as enc_counts_per_rev value was there in Josh Newans' example, but since I'm not using encoders, I deemed it unimportant to change it, so I left it like that. Modifying it does seem to change wheel speed, but only to lower it, and the discrepancy with odom still occurs.

my suggestion again: measure the speed, and calibrate it so that rad/s of the joint velocity is correct.

@ChristophFroehlich So I did that and it gave me about 8 rad/s. Putting that into ros2_control.xacro didn't seem to change much, especially when turning, which is still way off.

so you can confirm that if you command 1rad/s (with a velocity_controller for example) that you get the correct speed?

@ChristophFroehlich It's weird, when I send commands with ros2 topic pub /diff_cont/cmd_vel_unstamped geometry_msgs/msg/Twist "{linear: {x: (some number), y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}", it doesn't seem to matter what speed I set, it always goes at the same speed and the only thing that changes slightly is the acceleration.

maybe you are already in the max velocity limit of your actuators

@ChristophFroehlich Yes, it seems so, but it's always just a tad less than the odom expects, for some reason, which is my problem.
